# Does the new asp:chart control need to be installed on the server or can it be used from the bin folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, hosting, charts

- I have installed the new `asp:chart` control on my machine and have built an app that uses it.
- All is working well so far.  Now I want to deploy my app in a hosted environment.
- If my hosting provider doesn't have the `asp:chart` control installed can I get my app to work by putting the `.dll` in the bin folder?

  (I guess I am asking if it has to be found in the Gac)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from deploying the assembly to the bin folder, you also need to configure a folder with write permission to temporarily store the chart images.

In web.config under

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=D:\TEMPDUMP\;"/>
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

It does not have to be in the GAC.  Applications will look in the GAC if it can't find it in the bin folder.

Comment: I know that the app will look in the GAC if it isn't found in the bin.  However not all assemblies work from the .bin folder.  Take Crystal Reports for example if you mark all the .dll's as copy local and don't install Crystal Reports your app is still going to error out.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the .dll in the bin folder and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at [OpenFlashChart](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/), the charts look prettier

Comment: The Control does look decent.  Are there any examples using ASP.NET MVC?  I don't want to use any controls built around it for .NET.

Comment: i've been using it with web forms, so i cannot really answer that. 
i'll try to use it in a new project i have with MVC, but that won't happen before 1 month...

Answer (score 0):

There's one more step: Before you deploy it to your server, you must create a directory to use as a temporary directory for the chart images on the server and you must write it in  in web.config, like this:

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file; timeout=20; dir=c:\tmpimg;" />
```

You can use any directory that you want. Don't forget to set the right permissions in this directory. Keep security aways in mind.