# ASP.NET - deploying chart control

Tags: asp.net, charts

HEllo,
im using chart control in my website and locallly everything works correctly, but when i try to deploy, the page with chart doesn't work.
i found some kind of solution here:
[Does the new asp:chart control need to be installed on the server or can it be used from the bin folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807170/does-the-new-aspchart-control-need-to-be-installed-on-the-server-or-can-it-be-u)

but i don't know which dll should i copy and where can i find that bin folder?

Cheers,
Bart

Comment: Do you receive any errors or something?

Comment: only this: 

"Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine."

i set customerrors mode to off but myserver ignores this setting so i can't see the details of this error;/

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy to the application's bin directory (right under the top level of the application) or you can install to the GAC.  When deploying, you'll usually go with Bin directory deployment.

Comment: i created "Bin" folder in the root of my server. then i copied there System.Web.DataVisualization.dll, System.Web.DataVisualization.xml and System.Web.DataVisualization.Design.dll

but it didn't help;/ 
what else should i do?

it's really important for me...